# Let $G = U_{16}$, $H = \{1, 15\}, K = \{1, 9\}$, where $H, K $are subgroups of $G$. Are $H$ and $K$ isomorphic? How to prove this?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know the answer is yes, but I do not know how to construct a proof of it. A proof I came across online suggests showing that both $H$ and $K$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, and by transitivity are isomorphic to one another, but I don't understand why we know that $H$ and $K$ are both isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Can someone please explain why $H,K$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, or explain another method of constructing this proof?

Comment: There's only one group with two elements, up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

What do the multiplication tables look like? For $\{1,15\}$ you get

$$ \begin{array}{c|cc} * & 1 & 15 \\\hline 1 & 1 & 15 \\ 15 & 15 & 1 \end{array} $$

If you do the same thing for $\{1,9\}$ you get the same table except with $9$ in place of $15$. This tells you that

$$ f : \begin{array}{c&c} 1 \hspace{-3mm} &\mapsto 1 \\ 15\hspace{-3mm} &\mapsto 9 \end{array} $$

is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

We know $H$ and $K$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ because, both subgroups contain two elements, one that has order $1$ and one that has order $2$, and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ has two elements with similar order. Thus we can map each element of $H$ to the element $\mathbb{Z}_2$ with the same order. Similarly we can map $K$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Thus $H \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \cong K$.

Or we can explicitly construct an isomorphism $\phi : H \rightarrow K$  defined by $\phi(1)=1$ and $\phi(15)=9$